# Break Infinite Loop After SIGSEVG Signal

Tags: c, signals

I'm trying to find my maximum stack size with my program. I know, on my OS maximum size for stack is like 8MB. So I'm trying to make infinite loop until it cause segmentation fault. Then I need to break this loop so I can calculate size. How can I do that? Is there any way to break infinite loop after SIGSEGV signal?

```
 static void handler(int signo)
    {
        if(signo == SIGSEGV)
        {
            printf("Waoh, caught signal\n");
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int counter = 8964;
        stack_t sigstack;
        sigstack.ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
        if( sigstack.ss_sp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Err: malloc error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sigstack.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
        sigstack.ss_flags = 0;

        if(sigaltstack(&sigstack, NULL) == -1)
        {
            printf("Err: sigaltstack error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        struct sigaction act;
        act.sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK;
        sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
        act.sa_handler = handler;
        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL);

        do
        {
            char a[counter];
            counter += 8964;
        } while (1);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can `_exit()` in the signal handler to break the loop

Comment: *Then I need to break this loop so I can calculate size.* I'm not trying to terminate my program. I need to resume after that. That's why I need to break that loop.

Comment: Fork before the loop, then transport the result through a pipe or something like that to the main program. You could also try to recover with `setjmp/longjmp`, but I would try to avoid that hell...

Comment: Oh god, how couldn't I think that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your program to calculate an estimate of the stack size and then use *siglongjmp* to return from the signal handler to a presumably safe spot in `main` just before the loop that allocates the variable-length array. (Note that the way in which variable-length arrays are allocated is compiler-dependent and there may be no safe way to resume execution in `main` after it overflows the stack).

The *printf*s in the signal handler are just for debugging; they can be removed without affecting the rest of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

ptrdiff_t s_size_computed;
void *s_base_estimated;
sigjmp_buf env;

void handler (int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)
{
        printf("Caught signal %d\n", signo);
        if (signo == SIGSEGV)
        {
                printf("faulting address %p\n", info->si_addr);
                s_size_computed = (char *)s_base_estimated - (char *)info->si_addr;
                siglongjmp(env, 1);
        }
}

int main()
{
        int counter = 8964;
        stack_t sigstack;
        sigstack.ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
        if (sigstack.ss_sp == NULL)
        {
                printf("Err: malloc error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sigstack.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
        sigstack.ss_flags = 0;

        if (sigaltstack(&sigstack, NULL) == -1)
        {
                printf("Err: sigaltstack error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        s_base_estimated = &counter;
        printf("&locals %p\n", s_base_estimated);
        struct sigaction act;
        act.sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK|SA_SIGINFO;
        sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
        act.sa_sigaction = handler;
        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL);
        if (sigsetjmp(env, 0) == 1)
        {
                printf("computed stack size %td\n", s_size_computed);
                exit(1);
        }
        do
        {
                char a[counter];
                counter += 8964;
                a[0] = 0;         /* access element closest to top of stack (x86) */
        } while (1);

        return 0;
}
```

Here's the output on my Ubuntu system:

```
mp:~$ ./stack
&locals 0x7fffeb60e0dc
Caught signal 11
faulting address 0x7fffeae0d960
computed stack size 8390524
mp:~$ ulimit -s
8192
```